# why $routeChangeSuccess never gets called?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am doing something similar to below on my app but I am just not able to get the routeChangeSuccess event.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router", "ngRoute"]);

myapp.controller("home.RootController",
  function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $route) {
    $scope.menus = [{ 'name': 'Home ', 'link': '#/home'}, {'name': 'services', 'link': '#/services'} ]

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {

      alert('route changed');
    });

  }
);

myapp.config(
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        //template: '<h1>Home Screen</h1>'
        templateUrl: "/Client/Views/Home/Home.htm"
      })
      .state('services', {
        url: "/services",
        //template: '<h1>Service screen</h1>'
        templateUrl: "/Client/Views/Home/service.htm"

      });
  });
```

a very simple html as below also fails

```
  <body ng-controller="home.RootController">

    <ul class="nav">
      <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" "="">
        <a href="{{menu.link}}">{{menu.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view> No data yet!</div>
  </body>
```

but when i click on the link i see that the views are getting updated but the $routeChangeSucces event is never triggered.

is there something i am missing?

**Another question** I had was is there an event that I can hook on to to know the view is ready so I can start some additional processing, like document.ready().

[plnlr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uElxWeSHuSo2dBiZ1JoU?p=preview) but not fully working...

Regards
Kiran

Comment: `ui.router` is not intended to be used with `ngRoute`. Please use one or the other.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Please, check this wiki: [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events). An extract:

- $stateChangeSuccess - fired once the state transition is complete.

  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })

So instead of the `$routeChangeSuccess` use the `$stateChangeSuccess`.

To get more detailed information about all available events, check the wiki [Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#events-1). *Here you can find that the suitable for you, could be event `$viewContentLoaded`...*

Comment: thanks! $viewContentLoaded is what I was looking for. BTW I was unable to get the event $viewContentLoading though. not sure why. but the $viewContentLoaded works just fine

Comment: Analogously, check out `$stateChangeStart`.

Answer (score 2):

`stateChange` events are now deprecated and removed, use [transitions](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitions) instead.

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function () {
    console.log("state changed");
});
```