# Named view transition using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Is it possible for a named view in ui-router to make a transition to some other named view?

For example, in the snippet below, is it possible to move from `blue@bar` state to `orange@foo` state?

```
.state('foo', {
    url: '/',
    views: {

        '': { templateUrl: 'partials/a.html' },

        'black@foo': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/b.html',
            controller: 'SuperController'
        },

        'green@foo': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/c.html',
            controller: 'SuperController'
        },

        'orange@foo': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/d.html',
            controller: 'SuperController'
        }
    }

})

.state('bar', {
    url: '/ping/:x/:y',
    views: {

        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/e.html',
            controller: 'DuperController'
        },

        'blue@bar': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/f.html',
            controller: 'DuperController'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui-router` *transitions* are there for `state transitions`. Other words, there are no transitions among views.

What we can do, is to move some *named view* anchors (`ui-view="myName"`) into root or some parent state. Then each child *(grand child)* state can target any named view in its parent(s) hierarchy.

The best way how to understand that is to read this chapter from doc:

[View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

And check this snippet (cite from the resource above):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
    // This will get automatically plugged into the unnamed ui-view 
    // of the parent state template. Since this is a top level state, 
    // its parent state template is index.html.
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'   
  })
  .state('contacts.detail', {
    views: {
        ////////////////////////////////////
        // Relative Targeting             //
        // Targets parent state ui-view's //
        ////////////////////////////////////

        // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
        // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
        "detail" : { },            

        // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
        // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
        "" : { }, 

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Absolute Targeting using '@'                      //
        // Targets any view within this state or an ancestor //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Absolutely targets the 'info' view in this state, 'contacts.detail'.
        // <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html
        "info@contacts.detail" : { }

        // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.
        // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
        "detail@contacts" : { }

        // Absolutely targets the unnamed view in parent 'contacts' state.
        // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
        "@contacts" : { }

        // absolutely targets the 'status' view in root unnamed state.
        // <div ui-view='status'/> within index.html
        "status@" : { }

        // absolutely targets the unnamed view in root unnamed state.
        // <div ui-view/> within index.html
        "@" : { } 
  });
```

Also, check this sample app *(by ui-router team)*

- http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts

and its state defintion

- [state.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js)

small cite from the child state definition, targeting many different views:

```
///////////////////////
// Contacts > Detail //
///////////////////////
// You can have unlimited children within a state. Here is a second child
// state within the 'contacts' parent state.
.state('contacts.detail', {
    // Urls can have parameters. They can be specified like :param or {param}.
    // If {} is used, then you can also specify a regex pattern that the param
    // must match. The regex is written after a colon (:). Note: Don't use capture
    // groups in your regex patterns, because the whole regex is wrapped again
    // behind the scenes. Our pattern below will only match numbers with a length
    // between 1 and 4.
    // Since this state is also a child of 'contacts' its url is appended as well.
    // So its url will end up being '/contacts/{contactId:[0-9]{1,8}}'. When the
    // url becomes something like '/contacts/42' then this state becomes active
    // and the $stateParams object becomes { contactId: 42 }.
    url: '/{contactId:[0-9]{1,4}}',
    // If there is more than a single ui-view in the parent template, or you would
    // like to target a ui-view from even higher up the state tree, you can use the
    // views object to configure multiple views. Each view can get its own template,
    // controller, and resolve data.
    // View names can be relative or absolute. Relative view names do not use an '@'
    // symbol. They always refer to views within this state's parent template.
    // Absolute view names use a '@' symbol to distinguish the view and the state.
    // So 'foo@bar' means the ui-view named 'foo' within the 'bar' state's template.
    views: {
        // So this one is targeting the unnamed view within the parent state's template.
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contacts.detail.html',
            controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'utils',
            function ( $scope, $stateParams, utils) {
                $scope.contact = utils.findById($scope.contacts, $stateParams.contactId);
            }]
        },
        // This one is targeting the ui-view="hint" within the unnamed root, aka index.html.
        // This shows off how you could populate *any* view within *any* ancestor state.
        'hint@': {
            template: 'This is contacts.detail populating the "hint" ui-view'
        },
        // This one is targeting the ui-view="menu" within the parent state's template.
        'menuTip': {
            // templateProvider is the final method for supplying a template.
            // There is: template, templateUrl, and templateProvider.
            templateProvider: ['$stateParams',
            function ( $stateParams) {
                // This is just to demonstrate that $stateParams injection works for templateProvider.
                // $stateParams are the parameters for the new state we're transitioning to, even
                // though the global '$stateParams' has not been updated yet.
                return '<hr><small class="muted">Contact ID: ' + $stateParams.contactId + '</small>';
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

some other [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279522/) with more links