# AngularJS ui view autoscroll not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, autoscroll

I'm using Angular's ui-router but having a problem where when I click on a new view, the page doesn't start at the top but where it was. I set autoscroll to true in my ui-view like what others suggested but it still isn't working. I'm not sure what the reason is for it not working.

```
<ui-view autoscroll="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default option is true, maybe there's something preventing the autoscroll from firing, we need more code. Also you can make a custom code that'll work. Something like this

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you will see at this other [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454400/why-routechangesuccess-never-gets-called) '$routeChangeSuccess' will not work.  You need to change the code to look like this:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

---

Helpful UI-Router references (some gleaned from the referred-to SO Post):

- State Change Events: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events
- View Load Events: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events