# How to disable repeat event $routeChangeSuccess on page?

Tags: angularjs

I have code that detects routing in controller Angular JS:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
     if($routeParams.user){
       // AJAX 
     }
});
```

When I am on page with URL for this routing and do new AJAX request then the previous code is executed again. How to disable repeating executable?

Comment: you can disable the event like this: `var stopListen = $scope.$on('yourEvent', callbackFn);
 stopListen();` ... but that is not a temporary solution, it will disable the event completely, so you'll have to reset it somehow in case if you intend to use it again. [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: This solution helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456677/5403949